# Variable set in constructor is undefined in different method

Tags: coffeescript

I'm creating a library in CoffeeScript with calculating fares using Google Maps.

When initializing the map like so:

```
var viewport = document.getElementById('viewport'),
    options = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
        zoom: 8
    };

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function()
{
    var map = new google.maps.Map(viewport, options);
});
```

It loads as expected.

But when I initialize it using my library:

```
var viewport = document.getElementById('viewport'),
    options = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
        zoom: 8
    },

    map = new FareJS.Map(viewport, options);
```

The viewport remains grey and moving the map around gives `TypeError: a is undefined`.

After researching a bit, I found out that the value of `@opt` in the method `initializeMap` in the `Map` class, is undefined. I this find very strange since I set it in the constructor. Stranger still is that `@viewport` is **not** undefined... just `@opt`.

The class in question is

```
class Map
    constructor: (@viewport, @opt) ->
        if not window.hasOwnProperty('google')
            throw "Google Maps API could not be found, are you sure you installed it?"

        @loadMapOnLoad()

    initializeMap: () ->
        @map = new google.maps.Map(@viewport, @opt)
        return

    loadMapOnLoad: () ->
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', @initializeMap)
        return
```

Which, compiled, looks like this:

```
var Map;

Map = (function() {
    function Map(viewport, opt) {
        this.viewport = viewport;
        this.opt = opt;
        if (!window.hasOwnProperty('google')) {
            throw "Google Maps API could not be found, are you sure you installed it?";
        } 
        this.loadMapOnLoad();
    }

    Map.prototype.initializeMap = function() {
        this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.viewport, this.opt);
    };

    Map.prototype.loadMapOnLoad = function() {
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', this.initializeMap);
    };

    return Map;

})();
```

Why is it doing this and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `initializeMap` will be executed out of context of your class/object. `this` won't refer to your class instance in `initializeMap`. You'll have to do one of the following:

```
# explicitly bind to @
# https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind
google.maps.event.addDomListener window, 'load', @initializeMap.bind @

# preserve context with => and call regularly 
google.maps.event.addDomListener window, 'load', => @initializeMap()

# declare method with bound context, so it doesn't matter how you call it
# (resulting behaviour could be considered somewhat unidiomatic for JS, caveat emptor)
class Map
  initializeMap: =>
    ..
```

Comment: Using `bind` worked and results in much cleaner code than the second method. I have never used `.bind` until now. Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: That's debatable I think. `bind` can get a bit unwieldy... `@foo.bar.baz.bind @foo.bar` :)

Comment: Uhhhmmm... yeah... Good point. I guess it depends on the project, smaller projects can get away with it I'd say then.

Comment: `initializeMap: () => ...` in the `class` would be another option if you always wanted `initializeMap` to be bound.

Comment: @muis I believe that would bind the class, not the instance.

Comment: Nope, `m: => ...` creates a bound (to the instance) method, `@m: => ...` would be a bound (to the class) class method: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/trqrbt21/

Comment: @muis Why indeed, Coffee does some special trickery for this case. Didn't know that until now... :)